# php Regex preg_replace white listing

Tags: php, regex

`$text = 'sample sample sample #mark#24sdf-/u2<br>sample sample';`

```
preg_replace('/#mark#(\S+)/', 'marks : ($1)', '');
```

i use this regex to take some part text.

i want this -> `#mark#24sdf-/u2`
but regex out this -> `#mark#24sdf_/*u2sample`

Comment: What defines the end of the string? A less than always? The first occurrence of a non alpha/numerical character? You're expression currently is looking for all non-whitespace characters after #mark#.

Comment: Please show a sample of your desired output.

Comment: i want end regex output before '<br>'

Comment: Try `/#mark#([^<]+)/`

Comment: You want this output `marks : 24sdf-/u2` ?

Comment: pedro my contents line break using '<br>' so when this parts at the end of the line it takes next line first word too. i want stop this how we can do it?

Comment: chris85 your answer correct. can you post it as answer. i can mark it as answer. thanks!!

Comment: Sorry, I really would like to help you but I don't understated what you want. Make it clear , "I have this" and "I want this output".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$text = 'sample sample sample #mark#24sdf-/u2<br>sample sample';
preg_match('/#mark#([^<]+)/', $text, $findings);
echo 'marks : (' . $findings[1] . ')';
```

This says find everything that's not a less than symbol.

Output:

```
marks : (24sdf-/u2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's this that you want, but I guess so,

```
   $text = 'sample sample sample #mark#24sdf-/u2<br>sample sample';
   $text = preg_replace('/.*?#mark#(.*?)<.*?$/sim', 'marks : ($1)', $text );
   echo $text;
   //marks : (24sdf-/u)
```